# FBSession: user denies system-wide permission but callback still passed 'Open' status

Tags: ios, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the following code (Facebook SDK 3.1.1) to determine if a user has granted my app Facebook permission. I have found that when Facebook credentials are entered into the iOS 6 Settings app but turned *off* for my application, the following callback is called twice, first with `FBSessionStateClosed` but then with `FBSessionStateOpen`. This is also the same set of callbacks I receive when a user without system-wide credentials already has a token retrieved via OAuth, so I am not sure how to differentiate between these two scenarios.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if (status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
        // Handle access

    } else if (status == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed) {                                          
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        // Handle no access
    }
}];
```

Comment: We're looking in to this

Comment: @JamesPearce, what is the latest on this? I am having similar issues in 1.3.2 with permissions revoked via the web while the app is running.